# How to merge 2 sublists in a list of time intervals if the times are successive?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, list-manipulation

Given this calender of interval times when a person in booked :

```
list = [['10:00','11:30'],['12:30','14:30'],['14:30','15:00'],['16:00','17:00'],['17:30','20:00'],['20:00','21:00']]
```

example : The person is booked from 10:00 to 11:30,and is free from 11:30 to 12:30.
ps : Every sublist is an Appointment.
i would like to make a python script that can arrange the list to look like this :

```
output =[['10:00','11:30'],['12:30','15:00'],['16:00','17:00'],['17:30','21:00']]
```

where we merge the successive appointments when  the end Time of the first is equal to the end Time of the second.

Comment: refer to https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list = [['10:00','11:30'],['12:30','14:30'],['14:30','15:00'],['16:00','17:00'],['17:30','20:00'],['20:00','21:00']]


merged = []
for appt in list:
  if len(merged) == 0:
    merged.append(appt)
  else:
    last = merged[-1]
    if appt[0] == last[1]:
      last[1] = appt[1]
    else:
      merged.append(appt)

print(merged)
```

Gives:

```
[['10:00', '11:30'], ['12:30', '15:00'], ['16:00', '17:00'], ['17:30', '21:00']]
```